# What is the equivalent of `type` (used in bash and sh) in csh?

Tags: shell, csh

I want to check if a command is builtin or a separate program.
In `sh` and `bash` I use:

```
$ type <command>
```

What is the equivalent in `csh`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

csh has "which" (which cannot detect sh aliases)

In my environment using tcsh

```
~ (101) alias
cd      cd !* ; ls
q       exit
v       cursor; xhost + ;resize -s 40 80; unsetenv TERMCAP; screen
xl      xlock -nolock -random
y       Xearth; run xclock -geometry +1100+0; run nice xload -geometry +950+0 -update 3
~ (102) which y
y:       aliased to Xearth; run xclock -geometry +1100+0; run nice xload -geometry +950+0 -update 3
~ (103) type which
type: Command not found.
~ (104) which which
which: shell built-in command.
~ (105) which ls
/bin/ls
~ (106)
```

Comment: In the version `csh` on my system, `type which` shows that `which is /usr/bin/which` and not a builtin, so `csh` does in fact not have it.  It's a system binary.  So YMMV on this.

Comment: If you're using something with Linux or BSDs (including OSX), odds are that you're using tcsh.  Solaris uses "csh" from the early 1980s, and behaves as you indicate.

Comment: Actually, the `/usr/bin/type` on xyr system is a shell script that uses the Almquist shell as its interpreter.  Xe is thereby running the Almquist shell's builtin `type` command and seeing what is built into, and external to, the Almquist shell, rather than the TENEX C shell.  This is part of what's so tricky about the whole `which`/`where`/`whence`/`whereis`/`type`/`command -v` mess.

Answer (score 2):

Simply trying this shows:

```
$ csh
% type type
type is a shell builtin
```

So.. yes, you can?

Comment: give me
type: Command not found. with tcsh and csh on slackware

Comment: Doesn't work for me with tcsh...

Comment: what version? It works for me in both `csh` and `tcsh`.  `tcsh 6.18.01 (Astron) 2012-02-14 (x86_64-apple-darwin) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,color,filec`

Comment: Ironically, what's confusing you is the mirror image of what you said to M. Dickey.  On your system, the `type` command is an external command as far as the TENEX C shell is concerned: `/usr/bin/type`.  That external command is a small script that invokes [the Almquist's shell's builtin `type` command, which prints the message "is a shell builtin"](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/10/bin/sh/exec.c?revision=286813&view=markup#l745).   [The TENEX C shell would write "shell built-in command"](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/10/contrib/tcsh/sh.exec.c?revision=256281&view=markup#l978).